# Creating php matrix table in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a interactive task board where participants can ask questions to each other as in this image:

[image]

Below is how my View looks like. This generates the table design as shown in image above. But I how can I expand the tables functionality so that each tr -> td is bound/corresponds to a specific thead -> tr -> th?

```html
<table class="table" id="projTable">

<thead>
    <tr>
    <th></th>

<?php
foreach ($Participants as $Participant) {
    echo '<th> '.$Participant['username'].' </th>';
}
?>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php
$counttoken = count($Participants);

foreach ($Participants as $Participant) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td> '.$Participant['username'].' </td>';

   for($i=0; $i<$counttoken; $i++) {
       echo '<td> </td>';
      
   }
}

   echo '</tr>';
?>



</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i guess the solution lies in your db - just show your structure (how are those users connected to each other ?)

Answer (score 0):

DB structure:

[DB STRUCTURE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csWAA.png)